# How to add a loading bar while navigating from one page to another in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want a loading indicator while I navigate from one page to another in flutter. I am using the flutter_spinkit. First I have created a loadingScreen Page and when the user clicks on the button first the loading progress bar is shown later after a while I want to show the next screen where I am facing the issue as the loading screen was loading and not getting popped.

Here is my loadingScreen code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static String id = 'loading_screen';
  const LoadingScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Center(child: SpinKitCircle(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return DecoratedBox(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: index.isEven ? Colors.white : Colors.white,
            ),
          );
        },
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my button code :

```
 ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoadingScreen.id)
                        .then((value) {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);
                    });
                  },
```

Comment: Assuming you're using the loading screen because you have to load in some data, instead of having he loading screen be triggered on the first page, if you have something like a FutureBuilder on the second page, you can use `if (!snapshot.hasData) return SpinKitCircle(...) else *the second page*`

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you need to use any library to achieve it. if I were you I would create a base `viewmodel`, `bloc` etc and then handle `isProgressVisible` status in both base bloc(viewmodel etc) and base view(statefull,stateless).

if you are willing to use that library i would recommend you to look github issues etc.

Comment: can you please elaborate !!

Comment: i don't have enough time now to give detailed explanation but basically what I was trying to say is that managing loading bar status from base classes. and then the other classes that will extend the base class automatically handle it regarding the fetching status from backend. also I edited the answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply !! I will surely look after it.